# I'm getting this error while running the code in React Native error : node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: [BABEL]: Cannot find module 'node:path'

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, tailwind-css

I am getting this error while running the code in React Native expo with Tailwind

`Android Bundling failed 25ms`
`error:` `node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js: [BABEL]: Cannot find module 'node:path'`
`Require stack:`
`C:\Users\HPX\ipx\node_modules\nativewind\dist\babel\index.js`
`C:\Users\HPX\ipx\node_modules\nativewind\babel.js`
`C:\Users\HPX\ipx\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\module-types.js`
`C:\Users\HPX\ipx\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\configuration.js`
`C:\Users\HPX\ipx\node_modules@babel\core\lib\config\files\index.js`
`C:\Users\HPX\ipx\node_modules@babel\core\lib\index.js`
`C:\Users\HPX\ipx\node_modules\metro-transform-worker\src\index.js`
`C:\Users\HPX\ipx\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Worker.flow.js`
`C:\Users\HPX\ipx\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Worker.js`
`C:\Users\HPX\ipx\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js (While processing: C:\Users\HPX\ipx\node_modules\nativewind\babel.js`)

[image]

---

This is my **AppEntry.js** file :

```
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';

import App from '../../App';

registerRootComponent(App);
```

This is my **package.json** file :

```
{
  "name": "ipx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~47.0.3",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Please replay if you have a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use TailWind CSS with react native directly, as styling for HTML and ReactNative is different, instead you can use some library like [twrnc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twrnc)

Answer (score 0):

When you installed NativeWind there was an error in your console that your version of Node does not match the minimal requirements. You need to update to >=14.18

```
  // from the NativeWind package.json
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.18"
  },
```